# Pager not working in Magento 2

Tags: products, magento-2.1.3, grid-layout, pager

I am trying to create a gird with pager in my custom module, but it is showing all products in to one page. For this I have tried below way.

**Block/InventoryStatus.php**

```
<?php
namespace Training\LessionOne\Block;


class InventoryStatus extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{



    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $productCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status
     */
    protected $productStatus;

    /**
     * @var  \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $productVisibility;

    protected $_productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status $productStatus,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $productVisibility,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->productStatus = $productStatus;
        $this->productVisibility = $productVisibility;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Grid List'));

        if ($this->getProductCollection()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','vlc.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20))
                ->setShowPerPage(true)->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getProductCollection()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    // method for get pager html
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }


    Public function getProductCollection()
    {
        $productCollection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit'))? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;

        $productCollection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $productCollection->setCurPage($page);
        return $productCollection;
    }

}
```

**Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<?php
namespace Training\LessionOne\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
        //return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**view/frontend/layout/inventorystatus_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Training\LessionOne\Block\InventoryStatus" name="inventorystatus" template="Training_LessionOne::InventoryStatus.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/frontend/layout/templates/InventoryStatus.phtml**

```
<?php /** @var $block Training\LessionOne\Block\InventoryStatus */?>

<?php $list = $block->getProducts(); ?>

<?php    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();    ?>

<?php if ($list && count($list)): ?>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
<div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
    <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
        <caption class="table-caption"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Inventory Status') ?></caption>
        <thead style="background-color: #89d9e8;">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="col id"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('On') ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col Pre Order"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Pre Order') ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col Product SKU"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product SKU') ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col Product Name"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Product Name') ?></th>
            <th scope="col" class="col Date"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Date') ?></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php if(count($list) > 0 ){ ?>
            <?php foreach($list as $items){ ?>
                <?php  $product_obj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($items->getId()); ?>
                <?php  $sku = $product_obj->getSKU(); ?>
                <?php  $url = $block->getBaseUrl() . $sku; ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('On')) ?>" class="col id">
                        <?php echo "<input id='on_sku_$sku'" . " type='checkbox' name='on_sku_$sku'" . " checked='checked' disabled='disabled'>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Pre Order')) ?>" class="col date">
                        <?php echo "<input id='pre_sku_$sku'" . " type='checkbox' name='pre_sku_$sku'" . " disabled='disabled'>"; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Product SKU')) ?>" class="col shipping">
                        <?php

                        $image = "" ;
                        $image .= "<a href='$url' target='_blank'>";
                        $image .= $sku;
                        $image .= "</a>";

                        echo $image;
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Product Name')) ?>" class="col total">
                        <?php echo $product_obj->getName(); ?>
                    </td>
                    <td data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col status">
                        <?php echo $product_obj->getCreatedAt(); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" data-th="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('No Records')) ?>" class="col id">
                    <?php echo "No Records Found!" ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
<?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('You have no products.'); ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>

<style type="text/css">
    .custom-pager .limiter{
        display: block !important;
    }
</style>
```

see below picture all products are in to one page.

[image]

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change below in your prepareLayout function,

You had just missed **setLimit()** function for pager,

> $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);

```
   protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Grid List'));

        if ($this->getProductCollection()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager','vlc.history.pager')->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,15=>15,20=>20));
            $pager->setLimit(5)->setShowPerPage(true);
            $pager->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getProductCollection()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Remove var/generation folder and clear cache.

Comment: Yes, now working fine. But pager is not showing properly. any help on this? after I will accept this answer.

Comment: what's the issue in pager, please let me know

Comment: after 5th pager not showing `UI` correctly. see updated my post.

Comment: You can check from frontend side, I am not sure but might be Possibility from frontend side.